# How to unlock the final level?

Tags: 1001-spikes

I've finished all the levels in the game and gotten all the skulls and haven't done any skips with Aban Hawkins.

> I've reached stage 10-7, completed it (by grabbing the backpack) and got the outro and credits sequence.

But when I go back to the map there is still one level grayed out, how do you unlock it?

Answer (score 1):

The thing I was missing was the item that had to go into the slot above the backpack.

Where can it be found?

Hint 1:

> Unsurprisingly, it isn't hidden in 10-7.

Hint 2:

> It's in Ukampa. More specifically it's closer to the beginning than to the end of it.

Straight up answer:

> If you go to 2-1, on the same platform as the door, there is a passage to the right, going off-screen. Just don't get hit by the dart trap to the left.